# Why is the code not entering the if statement?

Tags: python, debugging, if-statement

In this code, I wanted to make a dictionary that would contain the encrypted version of a string. however, at the first if statement, the code seems to skip over both if statements and do not understand why

```
8   import string
9   
10  
11  drunk="abcdefABC"
12  joe={}
13  shift=4
14  for i in drunk:
15      for j in string.ascii_lowercase:
16          listj=[]
17          listj.append(j)
18      for x in string.ascii_uppercase:
19          listx=[]
20          listx.append(x)
21      if i in listj:
22          tempvara=ord(i)
23          tempvarb=chr(tempvara+shift)
24          joe[i]=tempvarb
25      if i in listx:
26          vartempa=i.lower()
27          vartempb=ord(i)
28          vartempc=chr(vartempb+shift)
29          vartempc=vartempc.upper()
30          joe[i]=vartempc
31  print(Joe)
```

*Coded in Python*

////

**Update**

```
import string


drunk="abcdefABC"
joe={}
shift=4

for j in string.ascii_lowercase:
    listj=[]
    listj.append(j)
for x in string.ascii_uppercase:
    listx=[]
    listx.append(x)
for i in drunk:

    if i in listj:
        tempvara=ord(i)
        tempvarb=chr(tempvara+shift)
        joe[i]=tempvarb
    if i in listx:
        vartempa=i.lower()
        vartempb=ord(i)
        vartempc=chr(vartempb+shift)
        vartempc=vartempc.upper()
        joe[i]=vartempc
print(Joe)
```

I've noticed that people were saying that I have placed the list inside of the loop so I took it out and declared it there but it seems as if it is not working and has the same problem

Comment: you initialize listj and listx for every character, so only `z` and `Z`make it into it.

Comment: Why make `listj` and `listx` at all? You could just use `string.ascii_lowercase` and `string.ascii_uppercase` in their place.

Comment: Note that `listj=[]; listj.append(j)` gives the same result as `listj = [j]`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski but when you append a character it adds that character into a list right?

Comment: @JohnRawls: Yes, but if you initialize that list to empty every time just before you append, you're always appending to an empty list.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I placed the initialization stuff outside of the loop but it still has the same problem

Comment: Your edit means you're not quite getting the point.  When your `for j in string.ascii_lowercase:` loop completes what do you expect `listj` to have in it?  It will have the last value in `string.ascii_lowercase` because you clobber `listj` with a new empty list on every iteration.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I thought that it would append all of the lower case letters into one list?

Comment: @JohnRawls: Try printing the list on each iteration as you append to it. What does it look like?

Comment: Forget the loop and just do `listj = list(string.ascii_lowercase)`.  Or use `string.ascii_lowercase` directly without making it a list.  `'c' in string.ascii_lowercase` evaluates to `True` (But so does `'def' in string.ascii_lowercase`.  Making it a list forces only single character comparisons to work.)

Comment: @FredLarson it prints out a-z separately

Comment: @JohnRawls: Exactly, Because each iteration you are starting out with an empty list, then you append that one letter to it.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski hey it worked, but can you please explain how it worked?

Comment: The statement `listj=[]` means create a new empty list and give it the name `listj`.  `listj.append(j)` appends one item to the list.  Since this is happening inside a loop the next time `listj=[]` is executed an empty list is created and the name `listj` now refers to it.  The single item list it used to refer to goes away because nothing is referring to it.  So this happens over and over.  Create list.  Add one item.  When the loop ends you only see the very last list that was created when you use the name `listj`.  If you move `listj=[]` *outside the loop* the problem goes away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You initialize `listj` and `listx` for every character, so only `z` and `Z` make it into it.

That means: for `a` you initialize `listj`, then add `a`. For `b` you initialize `listj` again, discarding the `a`. For `c` again ...

Using a debugger, you can find that out easily:
[image: PyCharms debugger]

As you can see, the variable `j` is already at character `c` but the list `listj` got cleared again.

Instead of declaring the arrays inside, move then outside the loop:

```
import string
drunk="abcdefABC"
joe={}
shift=4

listj=[]
for j in string.ascii_lowercase:
    listj.append(j)

listx=[]
for x in string.ascii_uppercase:
    listx.append(x)

for i in drunk:
    if i in listj:
        tempvara=ord(i)
        tempvarb=chr(tempvara+shift)
        joe[i]=tempvarb
    if i in listx:
        vartempa=i.lower()
        vartempb=ord(i)
        vartempc=chr(vartempb+shift)
        vartempc=vartempc.upper()
        joe[i]=vartempc
print(joe)
```

And, as mentioned by [@Fred Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10077/fred-larson), that initialization of the lists in a loop is redundant. You could also do

```
import string
drunk="abcdefABC"
joe={}
shift=4

listj=string.ascii_lowercase
listx=string.ascii_uppercase

for i in drunk:
    if i in listj:
        tempvara=ord(i)
        tempvarb=chr(tempvara+shift)
        joe[i]=tempvarb
    if i in listx:
        vartempa=i.lower()
        vartempb=ord(i)
        vartempc=chr(vartempb+shift)
        vartempc=vartempc.upper()
        joe[i]=vartempc
print(joe)
```

If you get rid of even more source code, you'll likely find that your code has a bug:

```
import string
drunk="abcdefABC"
joe={}
shift=4

for i in drunk:
    if i in string.ascii_lowercase:
        joe[i] = chr(ord(i) + shift)
    if i in string.ascii_uppercase:
        vartempa = i.lower()
        joe[i] = chr(ord(i) + shift).upper()
print(joe)
```

Note that `vartempa` is never used.